# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: ОШИБКА: база данных "name_db" уже существует - как проверить существование БД

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Начал изучать Python 2.7 + PostgreSQL 9.6.1. На питоне уже есть небольшой опыт работы, а с PostgreSQL опыта не имею. На просторах интернета нашел пример работы и создания БД.

Использовал найденный код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from psycopg2 import connect
import sys
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT

con = None
con = connect(user='postgres', password='poilk', port=5432)

dbname = "name_db"

con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbname)
cur.close()
con.close()
```

После второго пробного запуска кода выдается ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1531, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 938, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:/ALEX/Proktor/From_life_to_life/Work_with_db.py", line 15, in <module>
    cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbname)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: ОШИБКА:  база данных "name_db" уже существует
```

Как на питоне сделать проверку, существует БД или нет?

Comment: Вроде как по-хорошему создавать БД должен администратор вручную, а не программа

Comment: @andreymal так у себя в проекте и являюсь администратором) На данный момент вычитал, что можно вручную через различные СУБД сделать диаграммы взаимоотношений таблиц, а затем сгенерировать код в виде SQL запроса, который уже можно будет вставить себе в программу.

Comment: 1. В "папке" с проектом базы с таким именем нет, потому что механизм `"создать базу db_name"` это не то же самое, что `"создать файл db_name"`. Чтобы увидеть базу, вам нужно подключиться сначала к серверу БД (`c:\path\to\psql.exe -U postgres`), а потом почитать [документацию](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_steps)

Comment: 3. Используйте связку `try/except` же, ну! например: `try: psycopg2.connect("dbname='db_name' user='dbuser' password='mypass'"); except: print "cannot connect!"` ([документация](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ проверить существует ли уже БД - отловить исключение.

```
con = connect(user='postgres', password='poilk', port=5432)

dbname = "name_db"

con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cur = con.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbname)
except psycopg2.ProgrammingError as e:
    print("Already exists")
```

Еще методы:

Можно запустить `psql -l` - команда попробует подключиться к БД `postgres` с текущим пользователем и вернет информацию о всех базах данных на кластере. Команда после подключения опрашивает служебную таблицу `pg_database`. Эта служебная таблица общая для всех баз на кластере. Больше информации о служебных таблицах: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalogs.html

Можно проявить ненужную изобретательность и вместо `try/catch` также опросить служебную таблицу:

```
con = connect(user='postgres', password='poilk', port=5432)
# Без указания имени БД, соеденение будет с базой postgres

dbname = "name_db"

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname='{dbname}'".
                                                    format(dbname=dbname))

print(cur.fetchone())
```

Если ответом будет `1`, то база существует (по крайней мере есть запись в таблице).

Answer (score 1):

> Как на питоне сделать проверку, существует БД или нет?

```
select * from pg_database
```

Данный запрос вернет список баз на подключенном сервере. При необходимости добавьте условие в WHERE, чтобы найти нужное название бд.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я еще не настолько хорош в программировании, что бы понять как использовать Ваш ответ в своих целях.